# Usage differences between 'exit' and 'egress'?

Tags: word-usage

Are they perfectly interchangeable? Dictionary definitions seems to agree.

Comment: P.T. Barnum's American Museum was so popular that people would spend the entire day there. This cut into profits, as the museum would be too full to squeeze another person in. Barnum  put up signs that said "This Way to the Egress." Many customers followed the signs, not realizing that Egress was a fancy word for "Exit." They kept on looking for this strange new attraction, the "Egress".

Comment: @bib: I understand that snowy egress were much prized for their plumes at that time.

Comment: @SvenYargs I think the high point of egress fashion occurred when Edith Piaf bemoaned her utter lack of the fine feathered friend in *Je n'ai egrette rien!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two words are different. No two words are "perfectly interchangeable", although some word-pairs are sometimes *used* interchangeably. In this case, for example, 'exit' used as a noun may refer to "a *channel* of egress":

> 4. A channel of egress; an outlet. Esp. a door affording exit from a public building.

["exit, v. and n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66274?rskey=Pt7YSp&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed October 29, 2015).]

As an oppository to this sense of exit, then, 'egress' used as a noun may refer to "the action of exiting":

> 1. a. The action or an act of going out or leaving from a place; liberty to go out or leave.

["egress, n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59941?rskey=Bedr4h&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed October 29, 2015).]

Verbal uses of the two words differ similarly.

Comment: It seems dictionaries also list 'an act of leaving' for exit. E.g. 'his exit was hindered by the dog'. Similarly, entry seems to also share the meaning of 'an act of entering', e.g. 'her entry was swift and discreet', a meaning shared by ingress. I'm wondering if there are any reasons (for style, clarity) that cause one to use egress and ingress instead of exit and entry

Comment: @qedpi, yes, certainly. Real world example: when talking about the mass movement of spectators away from a sports field after an event, and their subsequent dispersal toward their next destinations, 'egress' covers it, but 'exit' does not. So, you can say "the post-football game egress went smoothly and quickly with public transit resources on hand", but "the exit etc." doesn't cover the same territory, and doesn't seem to me to even work for the use.

Answer (score 0):

I often use egress when talking about bigger places, or open areas like a football field, while I use exit for buildings, or cars, or any places with four corners and a door.

Comment: *Egress* is a word which I only ever see used by people like architects, road planners etc. But I have heard Americans remark on the fact that *exit* is not as much used in Britain as it is by them. Outdoor places, car parks etc., tend to have signs which say *Way Out*. I certainly would never say *those cars are having their egress blocked*. But I might say *that line of cars is blocked in - they can't get out*.